# .NET Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, sdk, .net-2.0

I'm new in Facebook API's, so I have a question cause I'm in seriously trouble with API's and Facebook's security politics!

I'm developing a WinForm socket application and needing Facebook integration for add a event to user's wall and I ***must*** use .NET 2.0

When I'm googling, I've found many sdk (for example; Facebook C# SDK -this one supports only 3.5 and 4.0-, Facebook.NET -this one supports 2.0 but it isn't working-, Microsoft Facebook Development Toolkit, etc.) but there are no working one with .NET 2.0, cause Facebook's security protocols perpetually changing.

Can anybody advice me a sdk or way for this scenario?

PS: Sorry for my English, I'm not native speaker though I've deal as possible as clearly.

Thank you in advance,
Luindale Ainion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid (due to the fact that 3.5 has been around since 2007) that all the .Net SDKs available need 3.5 or later.
You will have to create your own solution using the WebClient class and a lot of patience.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try that WebClient. I was trying to do that using WebBrowser and it is terrible!

Comment: Make sure you dispose the connections properly (use the 'using' code block). If my answer helped why did you not mark it as the answer?

Comment: It's not completely ended yet. WebClient hasn't get any advantage to me :/